# android key board period not appearing

Tags: java, android

I have developed a custom keyboard which has to be numeric and allow period symbol as well . Here is what I have tried but the issue is that period symbol doesnt appear when I type
keyboard.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="33%p" android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="0px" android:keyHeight="54dip">

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="8" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="9" android:keyLabel="2" />
        <Key android:codes="10" android:keyLabel="3" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="11" android:keyLabel="4" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="12" android:keyLabel="5" />
        <Key android:codes="13" android:keyLabel="6" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="14" android:keyLabel="7" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="15" android:keyLabel="8" />
        <Key android:codes="16" android:keyLabel="9" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="67" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_delete"
            android:iconPreview="@drawable/sym_keyboard_delete"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
        <Key android:codes="7" android:keyLabel="0" />
        <Key android:codes="\u002E" android:keyLabel="."
              />

        <!-- <Key android:codes="66" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
            android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_feedback_return"
            android:iconPreview="@drawable/sym_keyboard_feedback_return" /> -->

    </Row>

</Keyboard>
```

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_above="@+id/keyboard_view">
        <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/target"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.cognizant.customNumericKeyboard.CustomKeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboard_view" android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"></com.cognizant.customNumericKeyboard.CustomKeyboardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

BasicOnKeyboardActionListener

```
public class BasicOnKeyboardActionListener implements OnKeyboardActionListener {

    private Activity mTargetActivity;


    public BasicOnKeyboardActionListener(Activity targetActivity) {
        mTargetActivity = targetActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeUp() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeRight() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeLeft() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void swipeDown() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onText(CharSequence text) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
        long eventTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(eventTime, eventTime,
                KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, primaryCode, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                KeyEvent.FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD | KeyEvent.FLAG_KEEP_TOUCH_MODE);

        mTargetActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
```

CustomKeyboardView.java

```
public class CustomKeyboardView extends KeyboardView {

    public CustomKeyboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void showWithAnimation(Animation animation) {
        animation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        setAnimation(animation);
    }

}
```

KeyboardWidgetActivity.java

```
public class KeyboardWidgetActivity extends Activity {

    private CustomKeyboardView mKeyboardView;
    private View mTargetView;
    private Keyboard mKeyboard;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.keyboard);
        mTargetView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.target);
        mTargetView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                showKeyboardWithAnimation();
                return true;
            }
        });

        mKeyboardView = (CustomKeyboardView) findViewById(R.id.keyboard_view);
        mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(mKeyboard);
        mKeyboardView
                .setOnKeyboardActionListener(new BasicOnKeyboardActionListener(
                        this));
    }


    private void showKeyboardWithAnimation() {
        if (mKeyboardView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils
                    .loadAnimation(KeyboardWidgetActivity.this,
                            R.anim.slide_in_bottom);
            mKeyboardView.showWithAnimation(animation);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from link [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_PERIOD)

Change keycode to 56 for your period button. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The ASCII values for period is 46. Taken from http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/dot-full-stop-ascii-code-46.html